# How to use input

Tags: python

print('What do you want to do?')

donow = input()
if donow == 'AtariBreakout':

```
            webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

if donow == 'test':

```
    print("Test")
```

Changed code to most recent version. Still getting error, any advise?

Comment: So what happens if you run that code?

Comment: What exactly is your question? [How to let the user input stuff?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)?

Comment: It has no error. It just wont do anything. It says 'AtariBreakout'

Comment: Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Progamming\Python 3.4.1\Main Project.py", line 73, in <module>
    if input("What would you like to do?") == "AtariBreakout":
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @user3921959 have you set a variable called `input` prior to trying that call?

Comment: Error:   File "C:\Users\me\Documents\Progamming\Python 3.4.1\Main Project.py", line 73, in <module>
    donow = input()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation for [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input). Your code should be:

```
import webbrowser
if input("What would you like to do? ") == 'AtariBreakout':
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

*For Python 2.x use `raw_input` instead of `input` to get strings*

Answer (score 2):

Input is a really simple function in Python to learn.

Your code can work the way you have it now, simply by changing it to:

`if input() == 'AtariBreakout':`

However, if there are multiple answers that may be accepted, DO NOT do this:

```
if input() == '1': 
if input() == '2': #etc
```

This will keep prompting the user to keep inputting things. One method I prefer is this:

```
print('What do you want to do?')
#List of things to 
donow = input()
if donow == '1':
if donow == '2':
```

I like doing this method because it gives the user their own line to type on, although using:

`donow = input('What do you want to do now?')`

will also work. But this will prompt the user to type something on the same line that printed on.